# 1px border of table cell on some old android seems thick

Tags: android, css

I have a table with fixed table-layout. It works fine on iphone, but the border of table cell's width is inconsistent on a old android device with low resolution. some border is 1px, some other border seems 2px.

here is a Demo:

[Demo](http://codepen.io/leonz/pen/zrqxRq)

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <p>1</p>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a>

        <p>2</p>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a>

        <p>3</p>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>

        <p>4</p>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table td {
  border: 1px #c2c2c2 solid;
  height: 60px;
}

table td p {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

table tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 0;
}

table tr:last-child td {
  border-top: 0;
}

table tr td:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 1px #c2c2c2 solid;
}
```

**on an android device with low resolution:**

[image]

**on Iphone 5s**

[image]

**[Findings]**

If I change to width of table to a specific value, such as 305px, the cell's borders all become 1px on the old android device, so I think this issue may related to the device's rendered resolution.
Anyone encounter the same issue? Tnx for your help.